# Stack Overflow Exception in Unity Resolve

Tags: c#, unity-container

When i'm going resolve type from unity container `StackOverflowException` occurs in :

```
   public class UserValidator : Validator<User>
   {
        readonly IBaseService<User> _service;
        public UserValidator()
        {
            _service = ApplicationResolver.Instance.Resolve<IBaseService<User>>();
            RuleFor(user => user.Email).EmailAddress();
        }

    }
```

and `BaseService` :

```
  public BaseService(IBaseRepository<T> repository, IValidator<T> validator)
  {
     Repository = repository;
     Validator = validator;
  }
```

and `Register` :

```
container.RegisterType<IValidator<User>, UserValidator>();
```

should I change the pattern?

Comment: you have BaseService depending on Validator and Validator depending on BaseService... that results in cyclic dependency and results in stackoverflow exception. You should not have validator depending on service. Service should use validator to validate the entity and use repository to store/retrieve entity from the data store.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya i need validator in BaseService to validate entity,how to have validator here?

Comment: That's what I said.... You should use validator in service but should not use service in validator. @AmirNorouzpour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have `BaseService` depending on `Validator` and `Validator` depending on `BaseService`.

`Repository` to use store/retrieve an entity from the data store.